# Overriding EclipseLink EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, overriding

Is there a way to override the `EntityManager` provided by the `EclipseLink`?
I would like to override the `EclipseLink's` `EntityManager.remove()` method - I don't want physical removal(only logical).
It was easy to extend the appropriate `EntityManager`:

```
public class MyEntityManager extends org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl {

    public MyEntityManager(String sessionName) {
        super(sessionName);
    }

    public void remove(Object entity) {
        AbstractEntity en = (AbstractEntity)entity;
        en.setAuditRD(33333);
        this.merge(en);
    }
}
```

But how to pass its into EclipseLink's factory to create `MyEntityManager` instead of `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl`? Maybe is there any parameter, which I can pass in the `persistence.xml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `persistence.xml` class you have the `provider` element that decides that. Just put there your implementation of provider (not `EntityManager`). Excerpt from the JPA spec:

> 8.2.1.4 provider
>
> The provider element specifies the name of the persistence provider's javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>   class. The provider element is optional, but should be specified if
>   the application is dependent upon a particular persistence provider
>   being used.

Example of file:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="myapp">
      <provider>org.mydomain.ejb.MyPersistenceProvider</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the best solution. Unfortunately, because implementing persistence provider equals writing hundreds line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's improper to override default behaviour of entity manager. In case, you require to actually delete an entity, it won't be possible then.

It's better to have some helper wrapper class which encapsulates these methods, not directly accessing entity manager & then delegating request as required.

Below is pseudo-code.

```
/** Use this wrapper class instead of EntityManager*/
class DBManager {

  /** Implementing required methods*/
  remove(E e){
   em.remove(e); //-- Removing entity from DB
  }

  /** Give any appropriate method name to use application wide
     and implement custom logic, discarding entity logically */
  markInActive(E e){
    AbstractEntity en = (AbstractEntity)e;
    en.setAuditRD(33333);
    em.merge(en);
   } 
}
```

Comment: You are right (BTW I use `EJB` for that), but the problem is connected with managing the `JPA` relationships. Suppose, that I have an `EntityA` which has `@OneToMany` mapping to the `EntityB`-that means `EntityA` contains the list of the `EntityB`. Now, when I remove some `EntityB` from this list and call `EntityManager.persist(entityA)` I would like to remove `EntityB` logically, not physically. Unfortunately `JPA` calls the EntityManager and removes its physically. Ofc. I could iterate through the list and update each element separately, but why if `JPA` should allow for that?

Answer (score 1):

EcliseLink has support for soft deltes without needing to override the EntityManager.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/SoftDelete for details.  This allows you to change the delete query EclipseLink uses so that instead of deleting, it changes the field value.  You can add the @AdditionalCriteria to prevent the deleted records from being read in through queries, so that they appear deleted as well.

Otherwise, you can't get away with just overriding the remove method on the EclipseLink EntityManagerImpl unless you are sure you are not ever going to use cascading or private ownership.  The remove method delegates the work to internal methods have have more knowledge of each mapping, so if using any cascading options, you would need to override or intercept internal calls as well.  If you are not going to use cascade options, I would create your own set of persistence provider classes and a new persistence unit that uses these classes.  Your provider classes would then get look up the first persistence unit and delegate to it- similar to how most containers use proxy classes to inject factories and EntityManagers.